# Error 401 Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access

Tags: rest, api, postman, alm

In PostMan I'm trying to authenticate with RestAPIs provided in HPALM Guide (API Reference)

At first for authentication if I run this api "**almserver/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate**"

it gives

> 200 OK

but when I check the authenticated api "**almserver/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated**"

it gives

> 401 Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login
>   append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.

and if I append this '**?login-form-required=y**' particular line in the end of the second api  I will get html page as response

HP Application Lifecycle Management 12.53
background-color: #eee

whereas we expect this

[image]

Could some one please help me with this one?

Comment: Are u sending cookies back ?. You need to use postman interceptor for sending the cookies back. It works fine for me . See this [Postman interceptor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/interceptor_extension) , This sets the cookies Make sure the Interceptor is enabled in the Postman header toolbar.

Comment: @Macintosh_89 is right - there are two cookies which are sent back to client when you call almserver/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate:  
LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY and QCSession.  

You have to include them in all subsequent requests to HP ALM REST API

Comment: you should get 5 cookies back. send your request to http://qcurl/qcbin/api/authentication-point/sign-in , cookies u should get JSESSIONID,LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY,QCSession,ALM_USER and XSRF-TOKEN. As i said earlier you need interceptor  to make it work

Comment: I think this maybe happening because the authentication has failed.

Comment: I've succesfully made it to the point where i get back: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><AuthenticationInfo><Username>MyUserName</Username></AuthenticationInfo>    => But from here?, i try to present the defects (for example), sending the cookie i got, and yet, getting the same 401 as described here. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

@Sergi @Macintosh_89 I met the same issue with Manu, i post http://almserver***/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate, but only LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY return back without QCSession, do u knew why?

Comment: You need to send a POST request to `/qcbin/rest/site-session` with the LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY cookie. A QCSession cookie will be contained in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your request to `almserver/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate` will return a LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY cookie.

You need to add this cookie to the request to `almserver/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated`.